# Download the JIRA Timesheet using jira rest api

Tags: c#, .net, jira-rest-api

let me explain you what i have done. My req is to download all the jira issues and jira time sheet. I am done with downloading the jira issues using JIRA rest api url (https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=JRA) and for this i have created a console application which has rest client class using which I make a GET request call and for testing purpose rest api url is

"https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=JRA"

using this url i make a HttpWebRequest and get the response back in json formated string.
if i am not wrong then i have to do the same thing for downloading jira timesheet in json formated string but i didn't fin the correct API url for this to get the json formated string. Could you please help me in this?

Thank you,
Sagar Patil

Comment: I tried this url "https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/timesheet-gadget/1.0/raw-timesheet.json " but it didn't worked.

Comment: Can anybody answer my above question ASAP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Url 
https://issuetracker-domain.com/rest/timesheet-gadget/1.0/raw-timesheet.xml?startDate=05/sep/2013&endDate=20/sep/2013 
works for us. Please note, that timesheet gadget should be installed in server.

see also this: https://bitbucket.org/azhdanov/jiratimesheet/issue/269/time-269-restful-timesheet-endpoint